# Improving quality of sql text search results

Tags: sql

I have a table with column that is storing titles of articles.
User is typing search words for example "Germany car testing".
Search is done by using sql and like, and it looks like this ( based on number of params )

```
Select * from articles where title like '%Germany%' or title like '%car%' or title like '%testing%';
```

This works but, results are not satisfactory for the user, too many results are returned, results are not sorted by the number of words that are matched (example show first results that have all 3 terms ).

Am looking to avoid processing on beckend but I would consider it if it is not too processing time expensive ( using Java and SQL - EntityManager - MySql)

Are there simple ways to improve quality of my search?
I have around 10.000 records in table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not MySql expert, but what you might need is the full text search functionality. The good news is that MySql supports this function. See this [article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx). To use the full text search you will have to create a full text index on a given column or columns. Queries based on this index will be faster than using LIKE operator. Another advantage is that the full text search queries return results starting from the most relevant. It means that you will be able show a user only these rows that might be interesting for him.